# Android - listview row containing textview that has multiple lines

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

As the title says, I have a listview and the row contains among others a textview that has multiple lines.
Due to the fact that it has multiple lines it will behave like the pic shows.

Basically it should show only the first line, but what happens is the lines beneath are pushing up.
This only happens in ice cream sandwich and jelly bean. In ginger bread looks ok.

[image: pic]

Here's the XML code of the row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_list_row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/item_yyyy"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_weight=".14"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <TextView
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/item_dd"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_weight=".11"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <TextView
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/item_mm"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_weight=".11"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <TextView
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/item_state"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_weight=".13"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <TextView
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/item_pu"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_weight=".11"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <TextView
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/item_detailes"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_weight=".40"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried messing with android:padding in the row’s xml but with no result.

What can I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this line of code: android:singleLine="true".
Now It looks ok:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

try to add `android:weightSum` in your layout.

if my list have 3 column then in peren layout i add `android:weightSum="3"`

and in all child i add

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

check below code of list row file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

if you want to make it center then use `android:gravity="center"` in perent linear  layout.

Answer (score 0):

if in another place you have a multi line text and the same issu you can use

```
android:layout_gravity="fill"
```